# Where does typings search for Typescript definitions?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, typescript-typings

When I use `typings install mongoose`, it looks like the Typescript definitions are downloaded from
https://github.com/louy/typed-mongoose

Which seems very random. In the past, they used to download from DefinitelyTyped https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped, which was great as a central repository for all the Typescript Definitions.

What is the search path that typings uses now when I run `typings install ______`?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found it, the registry where typings finds its files is listed here: https://github.com/typings/registry

Answer (score 0):

You can find here: https://github.com/typings/typings

Install with npm:

## Install Typings CLI utility.

```
npm install typings --global
```

## Search for definitions.

```
typings search tape
```